# Flutter Webview Post form data

Tags: flutter, webview, form-data

I am trying to integrate **PayGoal** payment integration in flutter app. I have to send data in form of form data .

I have also tried using dio through which I am getting html file in response which on rendering web view is not live .

Below is my Code

```
    WebView(
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            debuggingEnabled: false,
            onWebResourceError: (error) {
              debugPrint(error.domain);
              print(error);
            },
            zoomEnabled: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
            onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
             
              controller.loadRequest(
                WebViewRequest(
                  uri: Uri.parse("https://uat.paygoal.in/order/v1/payment"),
                  headers:  {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                  },
                  method: WebViewRequestMethod.post,
                  body: Uint8List.fromList(
                    utf8.encode(
                      jsonEncode(map),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to send body in byte code simply convert map to string and remove json encode then send the post request

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).